# How can I display all woocommerce products on the cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want to show all of the WooCommerce products on the cart page, so it can be easy for users to add products to the cart and direct checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Ali Nawaz and Welcome to SO!

I think to build this "*You may also like*" section and offer some up-sell to your visitors, the Woocommerce extension you are looking for is this one: **[Cart Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/cart-add-ons/)**

Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/cart-up-sells-and-add-ons/

You may also consider using [PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/en), where this feature is natively integrated for free. As Woocommerce, this e-commerce platform is open-source and free to download/install.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to search for are phrases like [quick order form WooCommerce](https://www.google.com/search?q=quick%20order%20form%20WooCommerce&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS717US717&oq=quick%20order%20form%20WooCommerce&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0.367j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [WooCommerce bulk order](https://www.google.com/search?q=WooCommerce%20bulk%20order&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS717US717&oq=WooCommerce%20bulk%20order&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.599j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). I found [this free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-order-form/), and [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-order/) which was just recently released.

Personally, I have used [this plugin](https://orbisius.com/store/product/orbisius-woocommerce-ext-quick-order/) three years ago. It was a little buggy at the time, but they have come out with a few updates since then. IgniteWoo also has [a quick order form plugin](https://ignitewoo.com/woocommerce-extensions-plugins-themes/woocommerce-quick-order-forms-bulk-order-forms/) they have put out that looks good. So there's a couple more options for you if the free ones don't work out.